# how to know the size of the vectors you are assigningto?

Tags: matlab

i wrote a function y(x) , in this function a check is the input value abs(x(t))<= 2 then i want the output y=x; but i get an error

> "Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a
>   different number of elements."

, but i didn't define the size of y ! is it suppoosed to have a default size similar to the x size ?

```
function y = my_f(x)

y(abs(x)<=2)=x;
y(x<-2)=-2;
y(x>2)=2;
end

N=1000;
t=linspace(0,10,N+1);
t(end)=[];
x1=(3*sin(2*pi*t/4)+0.5*cos(2*pi*6*t));

y= my_f(x1);
figure;hold on; grid on;
plot(t,y,':r','LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: how do you expect `y(abs(x)<=2)` this to work without defining `y` first? You are accessing an undefined variable.

Comment: yes i understood my mistake thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `my_f(x)`, with `y(abs(x)<=2)=x;` you are setting only a portion of `y` to the full vector `x`, which does not fit. Furthermore, you did not initialize `y` yet, so indexing before its existence is a bit weird.

Since you want `y` to be equal to `x`, for the specified condition, you can just do this:

```
function y = my_f(x)
    y = x;
    y(x<-2)=-2;
    y(x>2)=2;
end
```

Funny enough, you don't need to define `y` to be a copy of `x`, as long as you assign the same number of elements. Hence, this also works (unrecommended though!)

```
function y = my_f(x)
    y(abs(x)<=2) = x(abs(x)<=2);
    y(x<-2)=-2;
    y(x>2)=2;
end
```

If you inspect `y`, you will see that the other indices, for which `abs(x)<=2` does not hold, will be set to zero.

Comment: or just save creating a new variable `y`, use `x` all the way: `x(x<-2) = -2;` etc.

Comment: this worked ! thank you so much , actually at first i did write "y=x" this after that i wrote "y(abs(x)<=2)=x;" , but this didn't work

Comment: @user7886490 if you want to correct the mistake in your original code, you need `idx = abs(x)<=2; y(idx)=x(idx);`.